# Prestashop Instant Checkout

Tags: authentication, prestashop, credentialscache

I've enabled Guest Checkout in PrestaShop. Visitor have to fill his data when making order. If same visitor (from same browser with cookies) make next order, it prevent him to fill his data (including email). How PrestaShop can do this? It can be different visitor only from same browser. Is there better way to logout guest than manually delete session cookie? Do you think that it can be bug?

Comment: I have solved it, but it costs many of hardcore edits...

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution is to edit file controllers/front/OrderConfirmationController.php

At the end of function displayOrderConfirmation() before "return false" add this line:

$this->context->customer->logout();